# $parent.$index not working inside ng-bind but works in the DOM

Tags: angularjs, indexing, parent, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-bind

My problem is that I want to dynamically generate scope variable based on the indexes from 2 nested ng-repeat directives. When I show that expression in the DOM it works fine but that same inside ng-bind does not work. (The $index work but $parent.$index does not)
Here is my code:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" ng-repeat="device in home.devices">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title pull-right">
        <a href="#settings">
            <em class="fa fa-cog"></em>
        </a>
      </h3>
        <h3 class="panel-title" ng-bind="::device.name"></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 text-center" ng-repeat="sensor in device.sensors">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">

                        <h2 ng-if="device.type == 'bm'" ng-bind="t{{$parent.$index}}{{$index}}"></h2>
                        t{{$parent.$index}}{{$index}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Image: [$parent.$index in ng-bind does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuKTh.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet the `$parent` is actually the scope created by the `ng-if`.

Try it without the `ng-if`, see if it works.
Then, use `$parent.$parent.$index`

Which is, of course, horrible.

You could do `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`.  It's still horrible, and leaves a nasty surprise to the next developer that sees that code and tries to improve it using `ng-if`. But hey, no `$parent.$parent`!

How to do it "properly", is a good question.

I would try not to use $index at all.  Is there some ID in `device` and `sensor` that you can use for the same thing?  That may have the additional advantage of always having the same value for a given item, no matter the order, if that's important.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. I am aware that this is't the best code but it will need to serve the purpose until I catch more time and find better solution.